# How to create custom fake backend?

Tags: qiskit, programming

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to create custom fake backends using qiskit with data we are retrieving from our real backends in the laboratory.
As I understand, the best way to create one is to use [`GenericBackendV2`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.providers.fake_provider.GenericBackendV2).

Documentations says, that we can specify:

- Number of qubits
- List of basis gate names
- Coupling map for the backend
- Instruction calibration settings

But what about other characteristics? For instance, I want to set T1 / T2 times or each qubit's frequency and maybe even some measurement errors.

Documentations says:

> The remainder of the backend properties are generated by randomly
> sampling from default ranges extracted from historical IBM backend
> data.

But can I somehow set it manually?